# How to build an hash from an array of class object in one statement

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to perform the following in one statement.

I have an array of class objects:

```
# >> articles.inspect
[
  #<Article id: 1,  category_id: 2, ...>,
  #<Article id: 10, category_id: 5, ...>,
  #<Article id: 6,  category_id: 9, ...>,
  #<Article id: 9,  category_id: 3, ...>,
  #<Article ...>
]
```

I would like (*by using one statement*; that is, "only one code line") to build an hash like this:

```
{
  "1"   => 2,
  "10"  => 5,
  "6"   => 9,
  "9"   => 3,
  "..." => ...,
}
```

where hash keys are `article.id` values and hash values are `article.category_id` values.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 >> articles.inject({}) { |k,v| k[v.id] = v.category_id; k }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Hash[articles.map {|a| [a.id, a.category_id]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 1.9, you can use `each_with_object`

```
articles.each_with_object({}) { |hash, article| hash[article.id] = article.category_id }
```